# How context differs in the async behaviour in Api and in Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

If I run this code inside an .net web api

```
public class ConfigurationApiClient : IConfigurationService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public ConfigurationApiClient(IConfigurationManager configurationManager)
    {
        ;
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(configurationManager.GetAppSetting("ApiUrl"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public Configuration GetConfiguration(int agentId)
    {
        return GetConfigurationAsync(agentId).Result;
    }

    private async Task<Configuration> GetConfigurationAsync(int agentId)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync("resource").ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Configuration>();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Exception when getting  configuration for agent: {0}", agentId), ex);
        }
    }

}
```

I depend on the `ConfigureAwait(false)` to make it work, if I remove that it enters in a death lock.

But still if based on this [example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) I write the equivalent of the previous in a console app

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var product = RunAsync().Result;
    }

    static async Task<Product> RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            // New code:
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/resource");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
            }

            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even if I read about the `ConfigureAwait(false)` I have not clear understanding why it works in the console and not in the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using await captures `SynchronizationContext.Current` unless told otherwise by `ConfigureAwait(false)`. When the code after the await is resumed it's posted onto that context. In UI apps that means running on the single UI thread. In asp.net apps (your case) it runs in the context of the original request.

Console apps don't have any `SynchronizationContext` to begin with so you can't deadlock to begin with.

You can check that for yourself by seeing what's inside `SynchronizationContext.Current`

However, using `ConfigureAwait(false)` should only be used as a last measure. Mostly you want to avoid blocking on asynchronous code.

Comment: Thanks @i3arnon, problem is that I would have liked to block it inside the GetConfiguration and therefore use that one in my sync workflow but didnt manage to do it. Without the configawait if i call to result in the sync one it enters in a dead lock